# Can I create two separate columns in a word file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I can create two columns in my word file, however I want each column to be separated from the other. What I am trying to accomplish is text down the left side column and pictures on the right side, however, currently when I reach the end of the page in the left column, it runs over into the right and I have to space the words down so that everything looks the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with two colums and one row. That should do it! Remove the borders if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

The way I would do it is, move the right hand margin on the top ruler as far as you want the text to go. Then insert your picture, click picture `Layout options` and choose `Tight` and move the picture to where you want it.

[image]

You may need to turn the ruler on in Word (Just installed 2013 myself and the ruler was off by default).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can easily do this- In the 'Home' tab, on the 3rd column labelled 'paragraphs', it has got many different column options- right side, left, side, and there is also a drop-down list that says two columns, three columns etc. Select the one that you want. However, remember to highlight all your text when doing this. Good Luck!